# Excel: How to yield the product of two corresponding cells in two columns in the cell of third column

Tags: excel-formula

I have an excel spreadsheet with three columns. I have entered many rows of number data in two columns. I have left the third column empty. I want excel to multiply each row's 1st and 2nd column and print the answer in the third column all at one go for all the rows.

Answer (score 1):

If the columns are adjacent insert `=RC[-2]*RC[-1]` in all cells of third column

Answer (score 1):

You can use vba

```
    Sub MultiplyCells

        x = 1
        For x = 1 To Rows.Count

            Cells(x, 3).Value = Cells(x, 1).Value * Cells(x, 2).Value

        Next x
    End Sub
```